# Does a base class method marked as `virtual final` introduce additional overhead?

Tags: c++, inheritance, methods, overriding, virtual-functions

Suppose I want to have a class `Base` with two methods: `foo(int)` and `bar(int)`. I want them to be defined in a way that:

- `Base::foo` has to be overridden in a derived non-abstract class
- `Base::bar` cannot be overridden in a derived class

The first objective can be accomplished by marking `foo` as `virtual int foo(int) = 0`, to make it abstract. The second requirement can be met by marking `bar` as `virtual int bar(int) final` to make it final. This is the resulting code:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual int foo(int n) = 0;
    virtual int bar(int n) final
    {
        return n + 42;
    }
};
```

And an example class derived from `Base`:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual int foo(int n) override
    {
        return n * n;
    }
    int bar(int n) // compilation error here
    {
        return n + 43;
    }
};
```

Trying to override `Base::bar` has triggered a compilation error just as we wanted.

Now, my question is: **Does marking a method as `virtual final` introduce overhead because of the function being `virtual` (dynamic dispatch) even though the function cannot be overridden anyway?**

## Edit

Don't mind the lack of the virtual destructor `~Base()` it isn't here to make the code shorter.

Comment: @Evg Fixed <gesture>facepalm</gesture>

Comment: @PeteBecker But then `Derived` could override it, couldn't it?

Comment: Hide, not override.

Comment: I guess the only real overhead is the function pointer in the vtable, compilers should be able to optimize it

Comment: "*cannot be overridden in a derived class*" Why make it `virtual` at all then? If its not `virtual`, then you cannot override it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler is likely to devirtualize this call:

```
struct Base {
    virtual int bar(int n) final {
        return n + 42;
    }
};

struct Derived : Base { };

int foo(Derived& d, int n) {
    return d.bar(n);
}
```

[becomes](https://godbolt.org/z/rxUDRA) with `-O1`:

```
foo(Derived&, int):
        lea     eax, [rsi+42]
        ret
```

whereas without `final`, we get an indirect call:

```
foo(Derived&, int):
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        call    [QWORD PTR [rax]]
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Do you know if the standard *mandates* compilers to do this or it is simply *allowed*?

Comment: AFAIK, a compiler doesn't have to do it.

Comment: @YanB. The standard doesn't specify how exactly virtual functions work under the hood, or how fast they work. (Same for most other language features.)

Answer (score 0):

In your case No overhead because your class doesn't inherit from any class defines your final function so the compiler will generate direct call to its address regardless virtual declaration.

Here it is from actual code:

```
b->FoA(); //virtual inherited
002829A7  mov         eax,dword ptr [b]  
002829AA  mov         edx,dword ptr [eax]  
002829AC  mov         esi,esp  
002829AE  mov         ecx,dword ptr [b]  
002829B1  mov         eax,dword ptr [edx]  
002829B3  call        eax  
002829B5  cmp         esi,esp  
002829B7  call        __RTC_CheckEsp (02812E9h)  
    b->FoB(); // final
002829BC  mov         ecx,dword ptr [b]  
002829BF  call        A::FoB (0281366h)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you provide the source of your information (preferably a citation from the standard)?

Comment: @user234057356 The std doesn't prescribe a particular impl method.